# How do I get to Eglwys Gwyddelod Stone Circle?

Tags: wales

I'm trying to figure out how to get to Eglwys Gwyddelod Stone Circle.  I'll need to park somewhere and walk there, but [the](http://www.castlewales.com/eglwys.html) [websites](http://www.atlasobscura.com/places/eglwys-gwyddelod-stone-circle) [I find](http://www.ancientmonuments.info/wa2719-eglwys-gwyddelod-stone-circle) describing it don't give a lot of instructions.

Does anyone have any knowledge on how exactly to visit it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [first site you linked to](http://www.castlewales.com/eglwys.html), the key bit of information there is

> OS 135 SH 663002

That tells you that you'll want to get hold of the [Ordnance Survey Landranger Map 135 (Aberystwyth & Machynlleth)](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/shop/landranger-map-aberystwyth-machynlleth.html) to cover you for the walk you'll be doing. The numbers are the [grid reference](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/blog/2013/03/map-reading-skills-learn-how-to-use-grid-references/), which tell you exactly where on the map you'll find the stone circle

Looking at the map, the stone circle is a few hundred meters over (but some distance higher!) than a very minor road. The road in question has National Cycle Route 82 going down it, so it should be pretty quiet.

Officially, it looks like you should be making us of the car park that is about 2.5km west along the road, at 642986. Looks like you can probably find some nice circle routes around there, maybe going a tiny bit further west along the valley, then up and finally east to the stone circle.

Alternately, there are a couple of farms just east of the stone circle on the road. You might get lucky and find that one of the farmers is happy for you to park there, but I wouldn't count on it. There's no way you'll be able to park on the road, it'll be much too small!

**Update** If you don't have the map to hand, [this is the streetmap.co.uk view of the circle](http://www.streetmap.co.uk/idld.srf?x=266301&y=300214&z=115&sv=266301,300214&st=4&mapp=idld.srf&searchp=s.srf&dn=713&ax=266301&ay=300214&lm=1), and [this is of the car park](http://www.streetmap.co.uk/idld.srf?x=264001&y=298614&z=115&sv=264001,298614&st=4&mapp=idld.srf&searchp=s.srf&dn=713&ax=264001&ay=298614&lm=1)

Comment: You've got the map in question? :)

Comment: Online access to it at least! There's a few websites out there which let you browse OS maps for free, but they typically have very low per-day use limits, so it's not necessarily fair to link to them. Depending on your computer, you might be able to use [OS GetAMap free version](http://www.getamap.ordnancesurveyleisure.co.uk), but it's a bit picky and doesn't work for me...

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about that.  That is/would be a great way to check out some of my trip.  Thanks!

Comment: @dlanod www.streetmap.co.uk provides both 1:50000 and 1:25000 OS maps if you zoom in far enough, plus you can search by grid reference. I've never encountered any limit on page views there...

Comment: Wow, they're still going! It's odd, fully zoomed in is too far, you need to zoom out a bit to get the sensible walk map tiles. I've updated the answer with some links